# When does a channel block a goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

If I define a channel without buffer and write one data into it, does it block immediately(so that the kernel will look for another unblocked goroutine that reads from the channel), or does it continues execution and blocks when the next time some code tries to write into the channel again, when it hasn't been read yet?

Below are two pieces of codes I wrote to research on this problem.

code1:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0;i < 3; i++ {
            c <- i
            fmt.Printf("number %v inserted into channel\n", i)
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("number poped from channel %v\n", <-c)
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
number 0 inserted into channel
number poped from channel 0
number poped from channel 1
number 1 inserted into channel
number 2 inserted into channel
number poped from channel 2
```

After the first time c is written into, this goroutine seems to continue to be executed, since "number 0 inserted into channel" was printed.

code2:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    c <- 2
    fmt.Println("Something is written into channel")
    <-c
}
```

This piece of code cannot run correctly since a deadlock error is reported at runtime.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

From my view, when c <-2 is executed, the goroutine is blocked(if it's not blocked, the fmt.Println line will be executed and continuing executing will unlock c at <-c). When this goroutine is blocked, the kernel searches other goroutines and find none, so it reports a deadlock error.

In summary, in the first piece of code I conclude that writting to a channel doesn't block the goroutine immediately but from the second piece of code it does. Where did I get it wrong and when does a channel blocks a goroutine?

Comment: Also IMO the source is extremely readable (since it's in go!!! :) ) https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go#L142

Comment: It might help your understanding to break out the receive into a separate variable `j := <-c` (the compiler is highly likely to do this on its own).  Once the value has been delivered, either or both `fmt.Printf` calls can proceed, and there's no guarantee on which will happen first.

Answer (score 14):

Sending to a channel with no available buffer space blocks the sender until the send can complete; receiving from a channel with no available messages blocks the receiver until the receive can complete. An unbuffered channel never has buffer space - sends block until something receives and vice-versa. This is covered in the Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

Remember that your code is concurrent so you can't read too much into the order of output statements. A goroutine can be put to sleep in between the send/receieve operation and when your message is printed to stdout.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. I was trying to analyze the order of operations but totally forgot that it could be anything since they are concurrent. Upon verifying, the output that OP got from the first code is definitely one of the possible outputs.